# How do I return the count of multiple relationship types with one query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to get stats for a node based on relationships. For example, if I had a node "celebrity" with three types of relationships: FAN_OF, FRIEND_OF, and RELATIVE_OF how can I get the number of fans, friends, and relatives with only one query? I know how to do it with each relationship type individually, but I need to return them all in one query.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what your question is, this should get you close:

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH n-[r]->m 
RETURN n, TYPE(r), COUNT(m)
```

You would then restrict the matching relationships to your types (though none of these exist in the sample):

```
START n=node(*) 
MATCH n-[r:FAN_OF|FRIEND_OF|RELATIVE_OF]->m 
RETURN n, TYPE(r), COUNT(m)
```

Check it out and play around with it here: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=nbba2s

Comment: +1, this is probably better than mine because it doesn't assume people have all types. However, friends are usually bidirectional, as are relatives. This query might not work for those--but the data could be modeled to have two relationships, which would make this query easier.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this will get you started. It is helpful if you post some example graph data, especially on console.neo4j.org, so we can test out queries.

```
start c=node(...)
match c<-[:FAN_OF]-fan, c-[:FRIEND_OF]-friend, c-[:RELATIVE_OF]-r
return c, count(distinct fan) as fancount, count(distinct friend) as friendcount, count(distinct r) as relativecount
```